# How do I multiply an integer and a datetime value?

Tags: vb.net

Ex. I have an int variable with the value 90 on it and I have a dateandtime textbox with 52:00 on it (hh:mm), I want to subract the 90 minutes to the 52:00.

I do not know how to change the 90 to dateandtime format and later to subract two dateandtime values.

Comment: A lot, but I can't find out how to change a string value to a datetime value or a int value to datetimevalue

Comment: VB.NET IsNot vba.  DateTime must mean .NET

Comment: If you have already tried "a lot" then maybe show us some code samples of what you have already tried...

Comment: If it is in a TextBox, it is text.  Not a number and not a DateTime.  You need to have an actual datetime or timespan variable or parse the textbox to one before you can work with it as a DateTime type

Comment: It doesn't really look like using `DateTime` makes sense in this case. If you're dealing with just time the use the `TimeSpan` type. The `TimeSpan` structure has methods for converting a `String` or `Integer` to a `TimeSpan` and you can use methods or operators to perform basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I believe

```
    'assumes textbox has hh:mm
    Dim p() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(":"c)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(Integer.Parse(p(0)))
    ts = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Integer.Parse(p(1))))

    Dim intvar As Integer = 90
    ts = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-intvar))
    Debug.WriteLine("{0:n0}:{1}", CInt(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes)
```

Note that validity checking might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can use DateTime.AddMinutes(minutes)

remember this returns a new DateTime.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think the OP has a problem with type conversion and not so much the arithmetic :-)